# How to send a mail if pin code not Support

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

We have Support certain Pin code only if customer try to enter un support pincode i want to send a mail how to send that

```
 <?php
    class Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    {

        protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';

        public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){        
        $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
        $restrictedCodes = array(




    110001,
    110002,

); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;

    }   

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        /* Edited by vikas_mageworx */
        $postcode=$request->getDestPostcode();
        $countrycode=$request->getDestCountry();
        $items=$request->getAllItems();
        /* End Editing by vikas_mageworx */

        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();

        /*  one start */
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode,'items'=>$items);
       /*  one end  */

         /* tt start - ship charges never work  
         $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode);
         tt end */


        foreach($items as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }
```

**.phtml**

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, We cannot Deliver Product to Your Shipping Address, Please Change the "Shipping address and Pincode" and Tryagain.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>

---------

<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add email code in your after  error

```
if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
               $body = "Hi there, here is some plaintext body content";
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName('John Customer');
    $mail->setToEmail('customer@email.com');
    $mail->setBody($body);
    $mail->setSubject('The Subject');
    $mail->setFromEmail('yourstore@url.com');
    $mail->setFromName("Your Name");
    $mail->setType('text');// You can use 'html' or 'text'

    try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
    $this->_redirect('');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
    $this->_redirect('');
    }
     return $result;
            }
```

Comment: No i didn't got mail

Comment: did it show error unable to send??

Comment: No message .....

Comment: `if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;

    }` add code here maybe return from here

Comment: Ya i got it it redirct to shooping cart i don't want to redirct to shopping cart

Comment: How to send that pincode in that mail

Comment: `$body = $postCode;` simple add post code in body

Comment: Ya Got bro but i got two time mail

Comment: don't place code two time remove from one place or the maybe method calling is two time check that..

Comment: Can you please give some example of emai body  i try to add some content but not working. I want to add some text + pincode+ name i got the name

Comment: `$body = 'some text'.$postCode.'ddf'.$name;` like this

Comment: is it correct  $body ='Hi admin,' 
            'I am '.$name.'. I try to Place Order with this Pincode'.$postCode.'But I cant able to place order please check with it';

Comment: `$body ='Hi admin, I am '.$name.' I try to Place Order with this Pincode'.$postCode;` use that